# Parsley server side validation response

Tags: jquery, json, validation, cakephp-3.4

I am using **Cakephp3.4**, **Bootstrap**, **jQuery** for my project. For client side validation, I am using [Parsley JS](http://parsleyjs.org/). For server side validation I am relying on Cakephp validations. To save data I send Ajax request of Form data and get json response of success or fail. Now I want to display server side validation message for a particular field. My parsley validation setup can be seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kk4devxs/1/)

This is the response pattern of failed validation from server side.

```
{
  "result": {
    "status": "1100",
    "msg": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": {
      "email": "Email Already Exists"
    },
    "data": []
  }
}
```

I know that there is method of remote validation in parsley, but I can not (do not want to) use it as this is just small example while actual scenario will contain multiple fields and that would just make too many Ajax calls.

Does any one knows how can I show **response.result.errors.email** message in a tool-tip next to email input?

Comment: You can use any  two way data binding plugin for example, rivets js, that will be so easier when your json response comes / changes it will automatically change your dom object ( error messages in your case).

Comment: See API docs...http://rivetsjs.com/docs/reference/

Comment: Thank you @NitinDhomse  I will try it.